# converting character vector to unquoted names of objects

Tags: r, object, type-conversion, character

How can I pass a character vector naming existing objects to a function that only accepts unquoted names of existing objects?

```
devtools::use_data(..., )
?use_data: ...   Unquoted names of existing objects to save.
```

for example an alternative interface is provided by ?save():

```
base::save(..., list=, ) 
?save: list   A character vector containing the names of objects to be saved.
```

Example:

```
x <- "hello"
y <- "world"
save(x, y, file="./test.rda") # works fine
save(c("x", "y"), file="./test.rda")
>> Error in save(c("x", "y"), file = "./test.rda") : Objekt ‘c("x", "y")’ nicht gefunden
```

I'm sure this has been asked and answered many times but I couldn't find a solution. I unsuccesfully tried with the usual suspects as.name(), noquote(), get(), eval(), parse(), substitute(), etc.

The closest I got was

```
unquote(c("x", "y")
```

Thanks for any help or redirection

Comment: In this specific case you can do : `save(list = c("x", "y"), file="./test.rda")`

Comment: The example you chose might not be the best because save accepts character arguments as well as names. so this would work as well : `do.call(function(...) save(...,file="./test.rda"), as.list(c("x", "y")))` though you might want something looking more like `do.call(function(...) save(...,file="./test.rda"), lapply(c("x", "y"), as.name))` for other cases.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Can you sove the problem by not using list= but the ... argument for input, in save(), like I am forced to do in use_data(...,)?

Comment: That's what I'm doing with the 2nd option of my second comment

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Brilliant, thanks. Put your comment in an answer

Comment: Your answer will be enough ;), and better to use the form you used. If you use `rlang`/`tidyverse` you can also use `invoke(save, lapply(obj, as.name), file="./test.rda")` which is less awkward to deal with additional arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And this would be the answer based on @Moody_Mudskipper's comment

```
x <- "hello"
y <- "world"
obj <- c("x", "y")
do.call(save, c(lapply(obj, as.name), file="./test.rda"))
```

analog with devtools::use_data()